# Do I need a transit visa for Manchester UK

Tags: uk, transit-visas

I am traveling from Monrovia, Liberia to Saint George’s, Grenada. My flight leave Liberia on Sunday 9/16 and lands in Manchester on Monday 9/17. My flight from Manchester to Grenada is also on 9/17. Do I need a transit visa to get on the flight or can I transit without a visa

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you are a Liberian national you **will** need a transit visa. You can check for yourself on the [UK Government website](https://www.gov.uk/check-uk-visa).

> You’ll need a visa to pass through the UK in transit (unless you’re exempt)
>
> You should apply for a [Direct Airside Transit](https://www.gov.uk/transit-visa) visa if you arrive in the UK on a flight and leave again without passing through immigration control.

Comment: International connections don’t need to pass through Immigration https://www.manchester-airport-guide.co.uk/

Comment: @Traveller According to the Government link I provided a transit visa is required for Liberian nationals even when answering "No" to "Will you pass through UK border control".

Comment: @Traveller that doesn't seem to be supported by the page you've linked to. Even if it were, I'd trust that page an awful lot less than the advice from gov.uk.

Comment: @MrAndySweet I know, I was simply confirming for the OP that he won’t need to pass through Immigration (as referred to in your reply), in case the OP isn’t familiar with Manchester airport. I didn’t say he wouldn’t need a visa.